# igraph: convert list to vertex sequence

Tags: r, igraph

I am using the R implementation of igraph.
I did not understand why `get_diamenter()` returns a `igraph.vs` object, while `shortest_paths()$vpath` returns a `list` object.
I am trying to plot the shortest path between two nodes. I can plot the network diameter, since I can do

```
diam <- get_diameter(net_vc, directed=F)
vcol <- rep("gray40", vcount(net_vc))
vcol[diam] <- "gold"
```

But I cannot plot the shortest path in a similar way:

```
sp = shortest_paths(net_vc, from=V(net_vc)$Name=="I0", to=V(net_vc)$Name=="I11")
sp <- sp$vpath
vcol <- rep("gray40", vcount(net_vc))
vcol[sp] <- "gold"
```

It returns:
`Error in vcol[sp] <- "gold" : invalid subscript type 'list'`

How can I convert this list to a vertex sequence, so that `as.vector(sp)` would return the position of the vertices, so as to index `vcol`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for `get_diameter` says:

> get_diameter returns a path with the actual diameter. If there are
>   many shortest paths of the length of the diameter, then it returns the
>   first one found.

So it returns a single path. On the other hand, `shortest_paths` allows a *list* of `to` vertices. It will return a list of shortest paths, a list of igraph.vs's, one for each vertex in the `to` list. You will get a list even if you call `shortest_paths` with a single vertex in `to`. So, to set the colors the way you want you need to reference the first (and only) element of the list. You need:

```
sp = shortest_paths(net_vc, from=V(net_vc)$Name=="I0", to=V(net_vc)$Name=="I11")
sp <- sp$vpath[[1]]
vcol <- rep("gray40", vcount(net_vc))
vcol[sp] <- "gold"
```